# SQl Query : need to get the latest created data in the child records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirment in which I need to get the latest created data in the child records.

Suppose there are two tables A and B. A is parent and B is child. They have 1:M relation. Both has some columns and B table has one 'created date' column also which holds the created date of the record in table B.

Now, I need to write a query which can fetch all records from A table and it's latest created child record from B table. suppose If two child records are created today in table B for a parent record then the latest one out of them should get fetch.

One record of A table could have many childs, so how can we achive this.

Result should be - Columns of tbl A, Columns of tbl B(Latest created one)

Comment: Could you provide.. some data sample and Tables structure? It is better and faster.. everyone can check and help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the 'created date' is a DATETIME column. This would give you the most recent child record. Assuming you have a consistent ID in the parent table with the same ParentID in the child table as a foreign key....

```
select A.*, B.*
from A 
join B on A.ParentID = B.ParentID
join (
  select ParentID, max([created date]) as [created date]
  from B
  group by ParentID
  ) maxchild on A.ParentID = maxchild.ParentID 
where B.ParentID = maxchild.ParentID and B.[created date] = maxchild.[created date]
```

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks alot for your reply. However, i am not getting you query here. Like 'A.ParentID = B.ParentID'. I guess you want to 'A.PK = B.FK'. Can you please make me understand how this query is working?

Comment: You are correct, the primary key in table A is the foreign key in table B. The subquery find the most recent record for every PK

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query that can help you out.

```
select x, y from ( select a.coloumn_TAB_A x, b.coloumn_TAB_B y from TableA a ,
TableB b where a.primary_key=b.primary_key
and a.Primary_key ='XYZ' order by b.created_date desc) where rownum < 2
```

Here we have two tables `A` and `B`, Joined them based on primary keys, order them on created date column of Table `B` in Descending order.

Use this output as inline view for outer query and select whichever coloumn u want like x, y. where `rownum < 2` (that will fetch the latest record of table `B`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient but will work (SQL Only):

```
    SELECT [Table_A].[Columns], [Table_B].[Columns]
    FROM [Table_A]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table_B]
    ON [Table_B].ForeignKey = [Table_A].PrimaryKey
    AND [Table_B].PrimaryKey = (SELECT TOP 1 [Table_B].PrimaryKey
                                FROM [Table_B]
                                WHERE [Table_B].ForeignKey = [Table_A].PrimaryKey
                                ORDER BY [Table_B].CREATIONDATE DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407) to avoid hitting each table (or specifically `B`) more than once

Using CTEs to provide dummy data for `A` and `B` you can do this:

```
with A as (
    select 1 as id from dual
    union all select 2 from dual
    union all select 3 from dual
),
B as (
    select 1 as a_id, date '2012-01-01' as created_date, 'First for 1' as value
        from dual
    union all select 1, date '2012-01-02', 'Second for 1' from dual
    union all select 1, date '2012-01-03', 'Third for 1' from dual
    union all select 2, date '2012-02-01', 'First for 2' from dual
    union all select 2, date '2012-02-03', 'Second for 2' from dual
    union all select 3, date '2012-02-01', 'First for 3' from dual
    union all select 3, date '2012-02-03', 'Second for 3' from dual
    union all select 3, date '2012-02-05', 'Third for 3' from dual
    union all select 3, date '2012-02-09', 'Fourth for 3' from dual
)
select id, created_date, value from (
    select a.id, b.created_date, b.value,
        row_number() over (partition by a.id order by b.created_date desc) as rn
    from a
    join b on b.a_id = a.id
)
where rn = 1
order by id;

        ID CREATED_D VALUE
---------- --------- ------------
         1 03-JAN-12 Third for 1
         2 03-FEB-12 Second for 2
         3 09-FEB-12 Fourth for 3
```

You can select any columns you want from `A` and `B`, but you'll need to alias them in the subquery if there are any with the same name in both tables.

You may also need to user `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number` to handle ties appropriately, if you can have child records with the same created date.